# direct page with href

Tags: html, redirect

I have an web page which already hosted, and I define an hyper link in the page that direct to another page but when I click it add the link on to url..

For exp. my page: www.mypage.com and hyper link: go to page.`( <a href="www.anotherpage.com"> go to page. </a>)`

When I click "go to page." the url changes to "www.mypage.com/www.anotherpage.com" and of course displays page not found error..

Why it happen ? why the url changes to www.mypage.com/www.anotherpage.com I just want to direct www.anotherpage.com.

Comment: use http:// in the link. Otherwise it's a relative link

Comment: You need to use absolute URLs, eg. `http://www.anotherpage.com`.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with `www.example.com` then that is treated as a local part relative to the current URL. It won't (because it isn't allowed to) assume you intended to write an absolute URI just because the local part looks like it might be a FQDN.

You need to make the URL either absolute (starts with `http://` or `https://`, etc) or relative to the current URL scheme (starts with `//`) if you want to change the hostname portion of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an absolute url, starting with `http://` ? If not, the browser will act like if it was a relative path